# Mysql remove row - security issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a shopping cart that is stored in a database. When the user deletes an item it should be removed from the database.
The 1st approach that comes to my mind is to have a code such as:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='./remove_items.php?id=1'>remove</a>";
?>
```

and the page "remove_items.php" would call a sql query to remove the item with the specified ID (eg.: 1), and after that go to the previous page with:

```
header("location: index.php");
```

**the problem:**

*the page "remove_items.php" would be view-able in the source code, and therefore anyone could call it to hack my page with any item ID.*

possible solution: checking if the owner of that item is the same user who made the query for deleting - is this okay? other suggestions?

Comment: Yes it is okay to check if the owner is the one deleting it. Theres nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Why would users in shopping cart be able to delete products?

Comment: I believe the correct approach here would be to implement some sort of user management.  With user management, your server side PHP code would "know" whether or not a request came from an authenticated user.  And yes, if a user hacks himself, he could directly start deleting records from his cart, but another user would not be able to do this.

Comment: @Mihai: the user can change ideas about what he wants to buy, and therefore remove items from the shopping cart (not from the shop).

Comment: may be its okay in your case, you can use userid from session array to check the user authentication .Thus no way to hack .

Comment: Why are you storing the shopping cart in the database in the first place - it's not wrong but you have to manage it much more carefully than you do with a session-based shopping cart. For instance if a user simply closes their browser it'll leave a "dead" cart in the database. If the cart id isn't 100% unique (for instance, the PHP session id isn't unique over time) it could be "resurrected" by another user at a later date - simply by visiting the site they could inherit a shopping cart that isn't theirs.

Comment: no need to store the shopping cart in the db,make a session based shopping cart.User shoudnt  have delete access to the db in your case

Comment: @Mihai, shopping cart should be non volatile ,So a db is needed .like in amazons........It should be there when the user login afterwards.

Comment: I have read that the shopping carts should be recorded in the database for statistical reasons and the be persistent... even if the user closes the browser. In addition, I need to store the shopping cart in the database, at least when the user clicks to pay in order to track record of the items that are bought.

Comment: its for registered users only ,right? . checking user authentication using the session id first and then remove the cart if the user is valid is the best solution that I can suggest ,if you really want to achieve this using a GET call.

Comment: When you move to the checkout you'd generally create an order in the database (which *needs* a permanently unique id) and move the items in the shopping cart to an *order lines* table in the database. Generally speaking the cart itself is only really relevant for the current session. Statistics can be managed through something like Google Analytics or Piwik. So the only reason to store the cart itself in the database is if you want it to return when a user re-visits the site; which is a pretty edge feature and isn't worth the extra hassle IMO (even then you could use local storage).

Comment: can you suggest any shopping sites with a volatile shopping cart ,all famous sites likes amazon,ebay ,snapdeal ... have a nonvolatile one .

Comment: All shopping carts are volatile by nature. For instance: visit Amazon, add something to your basket. Close your browser, empty your cookies and revisit Amazon. No basket. If Amazon are storing the basket in the database they'll now have a dead and defunct basket sitting there. If that basket id isn't 100% unique (which it will be, it's Amazon) then someone else could inherit it. There's no 100% guaranteed sure-fire way to identify someone across sessions without them logging in.

Comment: I said that in case of registered users ,I think every site demands a signup before ordering items .

Comment: He told about hacking and all , what hacking  in case of a temporary store of cart details for an unregistered user.

Comment: Nobody has to register before adding items to their cart though (that would be weird) and many sites use *guest checkouts* (at least in Europe) so it's not true that every site demands sign-up before checkout (guest checkout is a standard feature in Magento even) - even PayPal doesn't require you to have a PayPal account any more when it's being implemented as a card payment system.

Comment: yep ,same for guest and registered , incase of guest a temporary id will be created, logged users have permanent id.guest id  and their cart can be deleted after they closes the browser .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) consider renaming your file, as if someone is nosing around your site as a shopper and see the name of the file, they know or can pretty easily work out what the file is doing. suggest renaming it to just something less obvious.

i.e.:

> item_count.php

2) as mentioned by [Mike Brent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720743/3536236), GET is wide open to easy and simple abuses, but while his recommendation of POST is better, it's *still* open to abuse unless appropriate measures are taken (see 3 below).

3) SESSION and OBFUSCATION. 
Each shopping unit (cart, user) should have an associated `SESSION` for their browser data, this is *not* really to store the data itself but to prevent [CSRF](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/csrf-attacks/) and similar activities spoofing one part of your website on another part of your website.

So, you can wrap the link to removing the item as a `POST` form with various hidden fields, one field should be a key value that is a unique reference generated each time the page is loaded, this reference is stored as a `SESSION` and then saved as a key, so then the recieving page (that deletes the product) can then match that the key in the form matches the key in the `SESSION`. This goes a long way towards preventing CSRF.

as well as this you want another hidden field to contain the `id` of the item to remove, of course.

...But the id should be not the *product* id but the **row id** of the row in the users shopping cart table row. So that when the page deletes the row it uses a cross referenced session id; so you take a `POSTED` value for the product,and then check that this value *AND* the session value for this cart (which is never shown to the user or their browser) match a row on the DB, if there's a match, then delete the row (or do any other action with it as needed).

### Example:

Table products :

```
Product ID
product Name
...
```

Table Carts

```
Cart Id
Cart SESSION_id
Cart UserAgent *see below*
```

Table CartRow:

```
CartRow Id
Cart Id
Product Id
Quantity
```

So what we have is that the shopper buys something, it generates (if not already existing) a shopping `Cart` row, which contains their unique session data (never revealed to the browser), as well as a hash (`password_hash` for PHP,or similar) of their user agent concatenated with their IP [to fairly specifically identify their agent (although not perfect) ]. The useragent/IP hash is required to limit the slim possibility of [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack).

so, then the product is added to their `CartRow` with a reference to their Cart Id and the product Id, then when you submit the form to remove the product  (or do any other basket action), you do a lookup request to check if the `SESSION id` and the `useragent` string hash matches and if they do get that **cart id**, *then* look in the `CartRow` table for the `POST`ed **CartRow Id** matching a row which also contains the `Cart Id`, once that row is found, bingo, you have authenticated the action so it's 99.999% safe to carry out and remove/add/edit their product.

Comment: Basket and Cart and generally interchangeable terms; I'd go with *cart* and *cart line* personally ... and add the *quantity* to the *cart line* table ... but yeah :)

Answer (score 4):

It is normally a REALLY bad idea to do any write, update, or delete operations via a GET call (i.e. parameter in query string).  You have hit on the reason why.

I would suggest using POST along with appropriate form security measures, user authentication and authorization controls, etc.

Parameters in query string (GET requests) are typically useful for cases where you have a read use case and you want the end user to be able to directly bookmark the resulting view (i.e. view a product page with product id passed in query string or similar).

Comment: **appropriate form security measures, user authentication and authorization controls** ... just to add emphasis :)

Comment: post is not that much more secure. It is definitely better than GET but it's still wide open for abuse, CSRF etc etc.

Comment: ... or even just using something like Tamper with Firefox - POST data is still basically just plain text over HTTP - it's the accompanying user-auth that's the important bit.

Comment: @Martin Correct about POST security, thus my specific mention of using appropriate security.  My comments on using POST instead are really to be in alignment with expected behavior of HTTP methods/verbs where GET is the method for read operations and POST is used for writing data (or also updating or deleting records in a web browser since PUT and DELETE verbs are not typically supported browser methods).

Comment: @MikeBrant I understand that and accept that entirely, but I felt it was worth mentioning that just because POST data is not directly shown to the user that it shouldn't be assumed by the user to be any more secure than GET data.

Answer (score 1):

**Session in php**
A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages.A session creates a file in a temporary directory on the **`server`** where registered `session variables` and their values are stored. 
A session ends when the user loses the browser or after leaving the site, the server will terminate the session after a predetermined period of time, commonly 30 minutes duration.

> My solution would be same for guest as well as registered one's , 
>   In case guest , a temporary id will be there , and a permanent one incase of a registered one.

- Store user id in the session variable.
- Check user authentication using that variable in the page for removing cart products.
- if user is valid then only do the delete operation.
- Since the `session` variable is available only in the server, using that for authentication is safe against hacking .

Comment: If you're tying the cart to the session - why store the cart in the database in the first place? Why not just use session variables? ;) Oh, and don't assume session data is safe from hacking : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack

Comment: Thats not I suggested (the cart is actually not in the session ), may be I can update the answer for you .For that hack , I suggest storing userid in the session and do an encryption (do the best one that is available ) while storing in the session variable . And decrypt it while checking user authentication .

Comment: Even if any eve (`the hacker`) hacks the session variable, it will be in the encrypted form .

Comment: only delete after checking the encrypted userid in the database for validity .Even if eve (`the hacker`) has same session id.

Comment: When a session is hijacked the hijacker becomes *you* as far as the server is concerned - they have your session id and would (with your example) have *your* user authentication and the site would look up *your* verifier in the database ... you have to use some kind of IP/UserAgent/whatever fingerprint to create a token to prevent session hijacking in the first place otherwise encrypting the user id is a bit like putting your key in a safe but leaving your valuables on display ;)

Comment: ... and I know your cart is *not* in the session - but it might as well be since the user-authentication to retrieve the cart *is* in the session - apart from being able to run abandoned cart analysis directly on the database I'm not seeing the benefit over just storing the cart itself in the session. There can be reasons to do it (storing carts across multiple domains maybe) but I don't think the person asking the question actually *needs* that level of complexity.

Comment: yeah :) , you are right .The encryption is only for keeping the id of the user safe , but for avoiding such complex things for preventing such  a kind of session hack , destroy the session as soon as the user closes the browser allow any thing while its been used by the users (jus for decreasing the level of complexity like you said).